# gitk cannot find a git repository (from windows context menu)

Tags: git, gitk

In Windows it is sometimes faster to check changes in files with graphical `Git Commit Tool` or `Git History` tool. These tools can be opened by right clicking on specific files that are in a git repository (displaying these shortcuts in context menu can be enabled when installing git from windows).

The problem I am experiencing is that **opening `Git History` from context menu results in an error message `Cannot find a git repository here`.**

This obviously is a problem, however:

- Opening `Git Commit Tool` by right clicking `Git Commit Tool` in
  context menu works fine.
- Running `gitk file.txt` from `MinGW` works fine.

The installation pretty much uses the default settings, so I am not sure what could be the problem.